# How to: Change target URL in iFrame using input text+submit fields & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I'm writing a random webpage during my downtime at work, and am coming across an issue where I cannot reliably set a URL as the "src" of an iframe that I, by default, have set to load http://getbootstrap.com. Any attempt to change the URL simply reloads the iframe at its default value.

I've attempted to apply previously documented solutions found on this site, and unfortunately have not had any success.

Here's some of the code I'm working with:

HTML5

```
<form name="browser" action="" method="post">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <input style="color:#000000;" id="addressBar" class="col-md-7" type="text" />
        <!--<input id="goBtn" class="btn btn-default col-md-1" type="submit" onclick="addressGo()" value="Go" />-->
        <input id="goBtn" class="btn btn-default col-md-1" type="submit" onclick="testCall()" value="Go" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <iframe id="browserFrame" class="col-md-8" src="http://getbootstrap.com" frameborder="0" >
            <p>Something went wrong...target website doesn't allow iframes to be used.</p>
        </iframe>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
...
<script src="..\bootstrap-3.3.7-dist\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="..\JavaScript\Custom.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
function addressGo () { //Function to browse to inputted address
    var addressBar = document.getElementById("addressBar"); //Declare Address Bar variable
    var browserFrame = document.getElementById("browserFrame"); //Declare iframe variable

    browserFrame.src=addressBar; //Set iframe URL as input from Address Bar
}

function testCall () { //Generic test function (to be re-written as needed)
    var addressBar = document.getElementById("addressBar"); //Declare Address Bar variable
    var browserFrame = document.getElementById("browserFrame"); //Declare iframe variable

    alert("Browser Frame: "+browserFrame+"\nAddress Bar: "+addressBar.);
}
```

Now upon testing, I receive the testing "alert" that reads with the following message:

Alert:

```
Browser Frame: [object HTMLIFrameElement]
Address Bar: [object HTMLInputElement]
```

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but I'm a little out of practice with coding. Any ideas are appreciated. :)

Regards,

~DanceLink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input id="goBtn" class="btn btn-default col-md-1" type="submit" onclick="return addressGo()" value="Go" />

function addressGo () { //Function to browse to inputted address
  var addressBar = document.getElementById("addressBar").value; //Declare Address Bar variable
  var browserFrame = document.getElementById("browserFrame"); //Declare iframe variable
  browserFrame.src=addressBar; //Set iframe URL as input from Address Bar
  return false;
}
```

The entire page will be reloaded when submit a form. In your case, better to put `go` button out of the form, so as to no need to `return false` and `onclick="return addressGo()"`.

Comment: Thank you, the code works. One thing though, you said I should have the Go button 'outside' of the form? Wouldn't that invalidate the above code then?